# Issue with updating value using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, updates

I am using angular js and am having a hard time figuring out how to update a value. I have tried and have just had no success. I will post my js file, if anyone knows anything about my issue help would be greatly appreciated. It is just updateTask that I am having an issue with.

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.todos = [
    {text:'task1', text2:'Mow the lawn', selected:false},         
    {text:'task2', text2:'Wash the car', selected:false}
  ];

  $scope.getTotalTodos = function () {
    return $scope.todos.length;
  };


  $scope.addTask = function () {
    $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.formTodoName, text2:$scope.formTodoDescription,  selected:false});
    $scope.formTodoName = '';
    $scope.formTodoDescription = '';
  };

  $scope.removeTask = function () {
    $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function(todo){
      return !todo.selected;
    });
  };
  $scope.updateTask = function () {
    if ($scope.todos.selected:true){
      $scope.todos.put({text:$scope.formTodoName, text2:$scope.formTodoDescription, selected:false});
      $scope.formTodoText = '';
    };
  };


}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Todo App</title>
    <header>Todo App</header>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">




  </head>

  <body>

    <html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/vast-shadow:n4:all.js"></script>
    <script src="//use.edgefonts.net/vast-shadow:n4:all;megrim.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="todo-wrapper" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <h2>You have <span class="emphasis">{{getTotalTodos()}}</span> tasks</h2>
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.selected"/>
          <span class="selected-{{todo.selected}}">{{todo.id}} {{todo.text}}: {{todo.text2}} {{todo.date_created}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form>
        <input class="add-input" placeholder="task name" type="text" ng-model="formTodoName" ng-model-instant />
        <input class="add-input2" placeholder="task decription" type="text" ng-model="formTodoDescription" ng-model-instant />
        <button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTask()"><h2>Add</h2></button>
      </form>
      <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="task.text"></input>
        <button class="update-btn" ng-click="updateTask()"><h3>Update Task</h3></button>
      <button class="clear-btn" ng-click="removeTask()">Remove Task</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js'></script>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>




  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Angular 2-way binding should take care of updating your view. Not sure what you mean. Can you provide an example?

Comment: So if there is a task that has been added and you want to now change that task, how would you approach that? I have been trying but I am rather new with angular so I am unsure as how to do this.

Comment: there's a disconnect in not knowing how you select task to update. Also `$scope.todos` is an array , has no property `selected` and syntxax for `if ($scope.todos.selected:true)` is invalid. Provide demo including html ...even if it's broken a bit

Comment: You need a unique key (such as `id`) on your `$scope.todos` array elements that you can use later to find/update elements. Also `Array.put` is not a function.

Comment: I select task to update with a checkbox i use selected for either removing or updating a task.

Comment: Well if you are using ng-repeat, you can use the $index to get the reference to that element. And then update that element

Comment: @emzy...helpful but not necessary to have ID. Simple to index object in array to remove or update

Comment: Okay thank you so if I have the id what would the method look like to update a task.

Comment: Within the `updateTask()` method you are using the `if` clause like `$scope.todos.selected:true` but `scope.todos ` is an array of object literals.

Comment: It will be beneficial to use id, that is the method I use in my backend @emzy

Comment: Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that your todos do have an `id` property from your backend.

```
$scope.todos = [
  {id: 1, text:'task1', text2:'Mow the lawn', selected:false},         
  {id: 2, text:'task2', text2:'Wash the car', selected:false}
];
```

Then to update one of them,

```
$scope.updateTask = function (task) {

  // search $scope.todos for the item to update
  var indexOfTask;
  for(var i=0;i<$scope.todos.length;i++) {
     if($scope.todos[i].id===task.id) indexOfTask = i;
  }

  // update the todo
  $scope.todos[indexOfTask] = todo;

};
```

You haven't posted your form HTML, but you'll need to pass in the task being updated in the submit handler.

```
<form ...>
  ...
  <input type="text" ng-model="task.text"></input>
  <input type="submit" ng-click="updateTask(task)"></input>
</form>
```

**Edit** Update your form inputs and submit button to pass the object through:

```
<input class="add-input" placeholder="task name" type="text" ng-model="task.text" ng-model-instant />
<input class="add-input2" placeholder="task decription" type="text" ng-model="task.text2" ng-model-instant />
...
<button class="add-btn" ng-click="addTask(task)"><h2>Add</h2></button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I will give this a try as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Sure thing. It would help if you add your form HTML to the question so I can make sure the solution is correct.

Comment: It's difficult for me to give you exact code since I don't have the full details of your project. Try to understand the design pattern though and make it work for you.

Comment: I did fix one typo though, try one more time.